# What sorts of javascript/jquery methods do you routinely code into your sites?

Tags: jquery, javascript-framework

I'm coding a core javascript object for my site, building in the common methods I use (and wrapping a few jQuery methods as well).

It's built like this:

```
var Core = {
  baseUrl: '/',
  lang: 'en-us',
  loggedIn: false,

  msg: function(str) {
    for (var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
      str = str.replace("{" + (i - 1) + "}");
    }
    return str;
  },
  include: function(url, success, cache) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: success,
      cache: cache !== false
    });
  },
  etc...
}
```

**msg** is a method to mimic C# String.Format, **include** lets me asynchronously pull in scripts. There are others (**formatDate**: converts datetime string to user's local time, **getBrowser**: gets browser types based on feature detection, **open**: opens a link in a new window, etc...)

This core object lets me perform a wide array of tasks... by just calling Core.*method*... moving nearly all of my javascript code into a .js file which can be cached.

Just out of curiousity, what sorts of common functions do you build into your sites?

Comment: What does that mean? How do I post to the wiki instead?

Comment: Only mods can make posts wiki now. I've flagged it for mod attention.

Comment: Its better suited for programmers.SE, now that its available for such conversations.

Comment: Good call, I'll add it there.

Comment: @Will, I posted the question to Programmers SE, they closed it. :D

Comment: @Chad one day, ONE DAY, it will be clear what should be done.  Sigh.  Where's the link?  I'd like to investigate further, if for no other reason than to understand wtf is going on myself.

Comment: @Will, here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29002/what-javascript-jquery-methods-do-you-routinely-code-into-your-web-apps-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually add a wrapper for catching any error pages.

```
ajaxErrorHandle: function (data, container) {
        if (data.indexOf("Server Error in '/' Application") != -1) {
            container.html(data);
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Cool, so instead of returning a JSON object that contains a success flag, you check the return data string to see if it starts with an error message? Not a bad idea, for those times you just want to return a small chunk of HTML instead of JSON.

Answer (score 4):

A logging function is one of the first things I add, if I can't start from [Paul Irish's boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

```
// usage: log('inside coolFunc',this,arguments);
// paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];   // store logs to an array for reference
  log.history.push(arguments);
  if(this.console){
    console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I use some string formatting functions, that are similar to other languages. Usage:

```
var s = 'Hello {0}!'.format('World'); // result is "Hello World!"
var person = { Name: 'Will' };
var greeting = 'Hello {Name}!'.formatWith(person); // result is "Hello Will!";
```

And here's the function definitions. I also use simple versions of map and reduce all over the place, not so much on external sites, but on an intranet I go all out with Javascript.

```
String.prototype.format = function ()
{
    var pattern = /\{\d+\}/g;
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(pattern, function (capture) { return args[capture.match(/\d+/)]; });
}

String.prototype.formatWith = function (obj, clean)
{
    return this.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/gim, function (all, match) { return obj[match]; });
}

function reduce(fn, a, init, limit)
{
    var s = init;
    var l = (limit == undefined) ? a.length : Math.min(a.length, limit);
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        s = fn(s, a[i], i);
    return s;
}

function map(fn, a)
{
    var l = a.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        a[i] = fn(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use the default map and reduce methods on Arrays in modern browsers. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Nice, I have a function that does a regex attribute match too... but only use when I need to match the same token more than once. Otherwise I use the str.replace method I showed above... it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

I use some convenience methods, handle dynamic theming, grab client info for error reporting and handle theming issues with .NET Postbacks in my core.  Here are a couple snippets...

```
    /**
    *   A convenience method for notifications that can be 
    *   called anywhere in the app, in place of standard 
    *   javascript alerts.  Assuming you define CSS for 
    *   the ID and/or are using jQuery UI, these alerts 
    *   are skinned.
    *
    *   @param string - the message that you want to display
    *   @example - alert('Hello World');
    */
    alert: function(msg) {
        $('body').append('<div id="alert">' + msg + '</div>');
        $('#alert').dialog({
            bgiframe: true
            , modal: true
            , width: 400
            , buttons: {
                Ok: function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); }
            }
        });
        return this;
    } // EO alert


    /**
    *   .NET Event Handlers
    *   When new code is added on to the client by way of
    *   .NET PostBacks, CSS is typically ignored.  This method
    *   can be used to add CSS to new elements as they are added
    *   asynchronously.  It calls a script at the end of every 
    *   partial post back request.
    *
    *   @example - Core.NETEventHandlers.AsyncPostBack.Init();
    */
    , NETEventHandlers: {
        /**
        *   Async Post Back Handler
        *   calls a script at the end of every partial post back request
        */          
        AsyncPostBack: {
            EndRequest: {
                Add: function() {
                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(Core.NETEventHandlers.AsyncPostBack.EndRequest.Handler); // where Core.NET... leads to this method
                } // EO Add
                , Handler: function(sender, args) {
                    // Handlers here.  Consider adding them into a separate method
                    alert('Hello World');
                } // EO Handler
            } // EO endRequest
            , Init: function() {
                Sys.Application.add_init(Core.NETEventHandlers.AsyncPostBack.EndRequest.Add);   // where Core.NET... leads to this method
            }
        } // EO AsyncPostBack
    } // EO dotNETEventHandlers
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing. I use ASP.NET MVC in my web apps now... this would have been nice when I used ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I had a great one for cross-domain ajax with an awesome wrapper, unfortunately I lost it for the moment until I can restore my HD. It was something like this though:

```
ajax = function(site, callback) {
    $.getScript('get.php?url=' + escape(site) + '&callback=' + callback);
}

ajax.find = function(url) {
    ret = [];
    if (url.match) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            if (url.match(this[i].url))
                ret.push(this[i]);
    }
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            if (url === this[i].url)
                ret = this[i];
    return ret;
};
```

I'm doing this by memory of stuff I wrote once long ago, but you get the point